# visualstudio addin move macros

Tags: visual-studio, macros, add-in, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-macros

VS.Net 2012 get rid of macros.

So I need to import my VS2010 macros to AddIn or Extension for using them with VS2012

There are many samples in the net, how to create buttons in toolbar with some actions. But I don't need buttons. I just want to attach my scripts with hotkeys in  `Tools\Environment\Keyboard`.

I tried to add in VS AddIn template in Connect class folowing code(like in my macros):

```
Public Sub MyAction()
…
End Sub
```

but it isn't shown in `Tools\Environment\Keyboard`.

Please, help with simple example, how to move my macros to AddIn

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate your macros as it is on the post [MZ-Tools HOWTO: Migrate macro methods to a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2013/MZ2013016.aspx)

To create hot-keys you need to have `Command`s wich can execute your migrated macros. They will appear in the <kbd>Tools</kbd>><kbd>Environment</kbd>><kbd>Kexboard</kbd> menu, and you can even add menu buttons for them.

If you change your mind about adding buttons, you can achive it through the <kbd>Cusomize...</kbd> context menu, or with your Add-In as it is shown in the Add-In template.